# Convert a given date/time to local server time

Tags: powershell, date, batch-file, time, date-conversion

I have a date/time, let's say 01/07/2021 20:50 (MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM) what is GMT-5 (EST).

My servers are running in different timezones, like GMT+0, GMT+9, etc...

I'm going to run a script using the EST date/time above. I don't want to bother about the local timezone of the servers because like I said they are in different timezones and could be inconsistent and I know that my downtime window for X environment/region is the time above in EST so I have to think in EST.

For instance:

```
reboot.bat 01/07/2021 20:50
```

And the above will run on the local server. It needs to convert but I'm struggling on it. I've been trying different options like `[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId` but no way.

Any help is much appreciated! batch or powershell would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Are you saying that the server on which you run your code is _not_ in the US Eastern time zone (ET,. EST in the non-DST period), but you need to pass a date to be interpreted as being in that time zone? Please clarify by updating your question directly.

Answer (score 0):

Use [a standard format that can include timezone information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601):

```
$localizedTimestamp = '2021-01-07T20:50:00-0500' # the -0500 postfix means UTC-5
$date = Get-Date $localizedTimestamp
```

`Get-Date` will return a timezone-localized `[datetime]` value